# google appsScript wait for batchUpdate results to take affect on slide

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I'm using the Slides API in my appsScript to change a tables column size, when later I query the tables column width I still get the old values.

When the script ends I can see in slides the table width has changed & next time I'll run the script it will return the updated width value.

Is there a way to wait for the request to finish?  Something else?

To reproduce, open an empty google slides and place a table in the first (and only slide).

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc Limits the script to only accessing the current presentation.
 */

function getColumnsWidth(table) {
  colsWidth = []
  for (var c=0; c<table.getNumColumns(); c++) {
    col = table.getColumn(c)
    colsWidth.push(col.getWidth());
  }
  return colsWidth
}

function changeColumnWidth(table, columnsInd, W){
  Logger.log('Called changeColumnWidth with columnsInd=%s, W=%s', columnsInd, W)
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var tableObjectId = table.getObjectId();
  var resource = {"requests": [
    {"updateTableColumnProperties": {
      "objectId": tableObjectId,
      "columnIndices": columnsInd,
      "tableColumnProperties": {"columnWidth": {"unit": "PT", "magnitude": W}}, "fields": "*"}
    }
  ]};
  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(resource, presentation.getId());
}


function getTableInSlide(selection) {
  var currentPage = selection.getCurrentPage();
  pageElements = currentPage.getPageElements();

  for (var i=0; i<pageElements.length; i++){
    var elementType = pageElements[i].getPageElementType()
    if (elementType == 'TABLE'){
      return pageElements[i].asTable()
    }
  }
  return Null
}


function myFunction() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var selection = presentation.getSelection();
  
  table = getTableInSlide(selection)
  var colsW = getColumnsWidth(table)
  Logger.log('columns width (before update): %s', colsW);
  changeColumnWidth(table, [0], colsW[0]*2)
  colsW = getColumnsWidth(table)
  Logger.log('columns width (after update): %s', colsW);
}
```

Output:

```
columns width (before update): [43.303149606299215, 181.63385826771653, 149.73228346456693]
Called changeColumnWidth with columnsInd=[0.0], W=86.60629921259843
columns width (after update): [**43.303149606299215**, 181.63385826771653, 149.73228346456693]
```

Next run output:

```
columns width (before update): [**86.60629921259843**, 181.63385826771653, 149.73228346456693]
Called changeColumnWidth with columnsInd=[0.0], W=173.21259842519686
columns width (after update): [86.60629921259843, 181.63385826771653, 149.73228346456693]
```

P.S
I'm using the slides API as I didn't find any better way to change a tables column width (if there is - I'd love to learn that too :)

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've added my code to the question (notice I know nothing in gs\js and improvising as I go from examples)

Comment: @NevenSubotic - I've updated the question with code example...

Comment: I was able to replicate and test your current code, but for further clarification, the script was working as intended. Can you further elaborate on this statement? "Is there a way to wait for the request to finish? Something else?" because the reason why the updated values are already appearing on the logs is because the request is already finished

Answer (score 2):

I recommend giving it some time before checking for the updated value. The function to try is `Utilities.sleep(numberOfSeconds)`, see [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds).

Basically, before you prepend it to this section as shown here:

```
Utilities.sleep(1000)
colsW = getColumnsWidth(table)
Logger.log('columns width (after update): %s', colsW);
```

If that does not work then I suggest you explicitly load the updated file again, e.g.

```
 
 const originalTable = getTableInSlide()
 changeColumnWidth(originalTable, 1, 2,)
 const updatedTable =  getTableInSlide()
 const newWidth = getColumnsWidth(updatedTable)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was looking how to interduce a sleep and couldn't find it.
Sadly this didn't help, I enter a 10,000 milisec sleep (the parameter into sleep is actually in milliseconds not seconds), I can see the affect of the resize ~immediately on the table but I still get the same result

Comment: I updated my suggestions above

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully got the example, but I had a similar problem. I solved it by using the following command:
`saveAndClose()`
Then reopening the Presentation. It forces execution completion.